# Data type conversion Numeric to String/ Character

Tags: r

How can I change numeric class x = 5 to a character class.

Comment: there is a typo in `as.character(x)` as you've written it there. What error do you get with either option?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a numeric to string, you can use the toString() function. But you said that the toString() function is not working, Please make sure you are using the function correctly. Below is a snippet that demonstrates conversion of "numeric" to "string"

```
x=5
print(class(x)) # output is "numeric"

new_x = toString(x)  # Converting x to a string here

print(class(new_x))  # output is "character"
print(new_x)  #output is "55"
print(x)  #output is 55
```

Answer (score 0):

Change class of a variable from numeric to character with as.character() function

```
#assign x to 5 (numeric)
x <- 5 

# check class of x (=numeric)
class(x)
# output: [1] "numeric"

# change x class to character
x <- as.character(x)

# check x class (= character)
class(x)

# output: [1] "character"
```